# Adding generics to ArrayUtils.toMap

Tags: java, generics

there is an open-source util library from Apache, where I found a method to convert an array into a map:

```
public static Map toMap(Object[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final Map map = new HashMap((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object object = array[i];
        if (object instanceof Map.Entry) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) object;
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        } else if (object instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] entry = (Object[]) object;
            if (entry.length < 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array element " + i + ", '"
                    + object
                    + "', has a length less than 2");
            }
            map.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array element " + i + ", '"
                    + object
                    + "', is neither of type Map.Entry nor an Array");
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Because I don't like warnings, I tried to add generics. But I don't know how to transfer the datatype from the input array to the output map.

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you want to convert your array into a map?  What type is your array?

Comment: if your goal is simply to get rid of warnings, why not use wildcards?
Map<?, ?>
Map.Entry<?>
etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method allows the incoming array to be treated as either an array of `Map.Entry`, **or** a 2D array where each row is a key/value pair. This proves to be a problem because **depending on what you find in the array**, you would need to choose **different** generic type values for the Map you return.

**One solution** is to cheat a little and use Java's generic type inference that applies to assignments. If you add generic type arguments `K` and `V` to `toMap` but don't use them in the rest of the method signature, they will be **decided by assignment**. You can see this in action in methods like [`Collections#emptyList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList%28%29).

Your `toMap` method would then be implemented like:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Object[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object object = array[i];
        if (object instanceof Map.Entry) {
            Map.Entry<K, V> entry = (Map.Entry<K, V>) object;
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        } else if (object instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] entry = (Object[]) object;
            if (entry.length < 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array element " + i 
                      + ", '" + object + "', has a length less than 2");
            }
            map.put((K) entry[0], (V) entry[1]);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array element " + i + ", '" 
                   + object + "', is neither of type Map.Entry nor an Array");
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

And you would invoke this method like:

```
Map<String, Integer> myTypedMap = toMap(myArrayOfObjects);
```

This will remove the warnings that you see when you call `toMap`, but you'll notice that the `toMap` method itself is full of 'Unchecked cast' warnings because you're **subverting generic type safety for convenience**. If you pass in an array of `Map.Entry` values containing incorrectly typed keys or values, or you pass in a 2D Object array with incorrectly typed values, you will expose yourself to potential `ClassCastException` problems when you interact with the Map and use the keys and values it contains.

**Another solution** would be to reduce the scope of this method to only support cases where the array values are instances of `Map.Entry`. Your method could then be simplified and have a truly type-safe signature like:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Map.Entry<K, V>[] array)
```

I doubt this will prove to be a useful method though.

I think the short answer is to live with the warnings because you are doing something that is genuinely not type-safe. If you want a convenient way to turn an array into a Map, you may want to rethink the implementation completely and design a helper method whose semantics enforce type safety, e.g.

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(K[] keys, V[] values)
```

Without knowing your use-case though, I don't know if this method would help you.

Answer (score 3):

It is only possible if you create two separate methods: one that deals with `Map.Entry` elements, and another that deals with "array" elements (e.g. `{"RED", "#FF0000"}`). Here is the code:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Map.Entry<K, V>[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Map.Entry<K, V> entry = array[i];
        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return map;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Object[][] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object[] entry = array[i];
        map.put((K) entry[0], (V) entry[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Even though some some of the code is duplicated, it is arguably more elegant. I'm afraid there is no better solution for the second method; `array` can only be reified at runtime. Thus, "unchecked" casts have to be made.

Answer (score 2):

Not here, because the function accepts both `Map.Entry` and arbitrary length 2 arrays as elements of the `array`.  I.e. unless you are willing to settle with something more strict (`Map.Entry <K, V> [] array`, for instance), generics are not possible to have.

Though maybe it is possible to overload the function on parameter type, so that different overloads return `Map <K, V>` when those can be established, while the common fallback always returns `Map <Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, for the very simple reason that this function is not properly typed. It takes an array of things which could be `Map.Entry`, or could be `Object[]`. There's no sane way to put generics on that.

What you would have to do is split it into two methods, one that takes an array of `Map.Entry`, and one that takes an `Object[][]`. The former looks like this:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Map.Entry<K, V>[] array) {
    // ...
    final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
```

The Object[][] one is considerably trickier. Broadly speaking, i think you have two options. Either:

```
// keys and values are the same type
public static <T> Map<T, T> toMap(T[][] array) {
    // ...
    final Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<T, T>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    // ...
            map.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
```

Or:

```
// let the array be loosely typed, but pass in type tokens for the key and value
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Object[][] array, Class<K> keyClass, Class<V> valueClass) {
    // ...
    final Map<T, T> map = new HashMap<T, T>((int) (array.length * 1.5));
    // ...
            map.put(keyClass.cast(entry[0]), valueClass.cast(entry[1]));
```

Comment: +1 for providing only type-safe solutions. I would point out your final solution could be used for his general case (make `toMap(Object[], Class<K>, Class<V>)`).

Comment: Yes, it could, couldn't it? Although i wouldn't - i don't believe in the existence of a situation where you have an array, but don't know if it contains entries or arrays. Moreover, if someone finds themselves in that situation, they don't need a routine to get them out of it, they need to take a step back and reconsider the code that got them to that position.